# magrittr placeholder gets duplicated in glue string

Tags: r, lubridate, magrittr, r-glue

I'd like to build a character value with the month name in it. I can extract the month name by using `today() >%> months()`, but as soon as I pipe the result into `glue()`, and start using the placeholder (`.`), the value behind the placeholder gets duplicated. Does anybody know what's going on here?

```r
library(lubridate)
library(glue)
library(magrittr)

# returns month name as character
today() %>% 
  months()
#> [1] "April"

# when piping into glue(), I get an unexpected output
today() %>% 
  months() %>% 
  glue("my_test_{.}")
#> Aprilmy_test_April
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `paste`? For example, `paste0("my_test_", .)`.

Comment: yes, I could use `paste()` but my actual code is more complex, and I'd like to make use of glues improved readability

Comment: Based on your current question, `paste` would be the preferred solution. `glue` requires named arguments, which is why it struggles when you pipe a nameless string. If you think `paste` won't work in your situation, can you alter the question so that it resembles your actual code more closely?